# how to switch users on least user server

Tags: php, apache, oop, nginx, server

i am working on an application where i have 3 apache servers and 1 nginx server now suppose if there are 10000 active users on my website and i want them to be distributed with 2500 users per server how do i do that with php i want users to redirect to 2nd server when 2500 users are on 1st server and it goes on with 3rd and 4th please can anyone help me with it. i tried with an example on nginx website

```
upstream backend {
server php-app1.example.com;
server php-app2.example.com;
}

server {
listen 80;
server_name www.example.com;
# enforce HTTPS
return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
listen 443 ssl;
server_name www.example.com;

location /some/path/ {
proxy_pass http://backend;
}
```

but dont know how to implement it with apache and going honestly i am not able to create any logic

Answer (score 1):

I believe that Nginx Load Balacing **does not work based on user count**, instead it uses well known load balancing techniques such as **round robin**, **least-connected** and **ip-hash**. By default if you don't specify the type of load balancing it will use **round robin**, according to your configuration, it is using round robin which is well suited to your scenario, you don't need to limit based on user count.

Take a look on the docs: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html

Comment: sir i do not want to enter in round robin term all i want to do is to switch users one every 2500 clicks to a different server than as i want to rotate them on all 4 servers can you help me with this in php